# number of days in month and months between two dates

Tags: jquery, performance, date, datetime, days

I need help to calculate months and days in months using 2 parameters of date picker.
months should not numeric.
E.g. i have two dates 01-01-21 and 01-03-21 the answer should be

January  31
February  28
march 31

Comment: so for each date within a given date range, you want to derive the month's end date? did you try something?

Comment: select to_char( add_months( start_date, level-1 ), 'fmMonth' ) months
      
      
      
      from 
      
      
      
      (select  :dated1 start_date,
                    :dated2 end_date
              from dual
              
              )
     connect by level <= months_between(
                           trunc(end_date,'MM'),
                           trunc(start_date,'MM') )+1--*+ 1..
i got months from this query but i also need days in each month.